# How to stop printing a string with condition?

Tags: c, string, char

I made struct called 'person'. I want to enter name and surname (by that order and they are seperated by space) of a person. In my code for some reason printf(); does not work properly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 3

struct person{
    char name_surname[50];   
};

int main(void){

    struct person M[N];
    int i,j;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){

        printf("Enter name and surname:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(M[i].name_surname);

    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(M[i].name_surname);j++){
            if(M[j].name_surname!=' '){
                printf("%c", M[i].name_surname);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]. You say that it does not work. In what way? What do you want, and what do you get instead?

Comment: @Blaze I think you mean `printf("%c", M[i].name_surname[j]);` and @klutt, you did not declare `j`.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX that's right, thanks for the correction.

Comment: @RoQuOTriX Say what?

Comment: `j` is undefined I said

Comment: Things like `fflush(stdin);` and `gets` were recognized as bad practice over 30 years ago, so I'd recommend to get a better source for learning C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you shared, it looks like you are trying to print only the first names. The following code should accomplish that:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 3

struct person{
    char name_surname[50];   
};

int main(void){

    struct person M[N];
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<N;i++){

        printf("Enter name and surname:\n");
        fflush(stdin);
        gets(M[i].name_surname);

    }
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<strlen(M[i].name_surname);j++){
            if(M[i].name_surname[j]!=' '){
                printf("%c", M[i].name_surname[j]);
            }
            else{
                printf("\n");
                break;
            }
        }   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`M[i].name_surname` - here `M[i]` can access beyond allocated memory because `M[]` has size `N` which is declared to be 3, while `j` could go up to the length of the name.
Secondly, `name_surname` is not a character - it is a pointer to a character. If you want to print the `j`th character, you need to print `M[i].name_surname[j]`. Alternatively, you could print the whole string with:

```
printf("%s", M[i].name_surname);
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters the function `gets` is not a standard C function. Use instead `fgets`.

This call

```
fflush(stdin);
```

has undefined behavior.

This loop

```
    for(j=0;j<strlen(M[i].name_surname);j++){
        if(M[j].name_surname!=' '){
            printf("%c", M[i].name_surname);
        }
        else{
            break;
        }
    }
```

does not make greate sense and has an invalid if statement

```
if(M[j].name_surname!=' '){
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Ay least you should write

```
if(M[i].name_surname[j] !=' ' ){
```

but in any case only one character will be outputted provided that the next printf statement will be written correctly

```
printf("%c\n", M[i].name_surname[j]);
```

Maybe you mean the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3

struct person
{
    char name_surname[59];   
};

int main(void)
{
    struct person M[N];

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Enter name and surname: " );
        fgets( M[i].name_surname, sizeof( M[i].name_surname ), stdin );
        M[i].name_surname[ strcspn( M[i].name_surname, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    }   

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        const char *p = strchr( M[i].name_surname, ' ' );

        if ( p != NULL )
        {
            printf( "%*.*s ", 
                    ( int )( p - M[i].name_surname ),
                    ( int )( p - M[i].name_surname ),
                    M[i].name_surname );

            size_t n = strspn( p, " " );
            printf( "%s\n", p + n );
        }
        else
        {
            printf( "%s\n", M[i].name_surname );
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter name and surname: Bobby Fisher
Enter name and surname: photosynthesis_bro
Enter name and surname: Thomas Man
Bobby Fisher
photosynthesis_bro
Thomas Man
```

Or the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N 3

struct person
{
    char name_surname[59];   
};

int main(void)
{
    struct person M[N];

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        printf( "Enter name and surname: " );
        fgets( M[i].name_surname, sizeof( M[i].name_surname ), stdin );
        M[i].name_surname[ strcspn( M[i].name_surname, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
    }   

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        size_t n = strspn( M[i].name_surname, " " );

        printf( "%c.\n", *( M[i].name_surname + n ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
Enter name and surname: Bobby Fisher
Enter name and surname: photosynthesis_bro
Enter name and surname: Thomas Man
B.
p.
T.
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it's just how you're looking in the array in the if statement and the next line that's not quite right - if you're intending to choose a specific character from the current string it should be `M[i].name_surname[j]`.

See if this works better:

```
    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(M[i].name_surname);j++){
            if(M[i].name_surname[j]!=' '){
                printf("%c", M[i].name_surname[j]);
            }
            else{
                break;
            }
        }   
    }
```